# Change the default user in vagrant guest

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I have to change the default user in vagrant guest. The user is vagrant, originally, but I need to connect as ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

- 1) Edit the `/home/vagrant/.bashrc` file, add `sudo su` at the end.
  This will make the shell switch to the `root` user when you log in.
- 2) Edit the `/root/.bashrc` file and add `su ubuntu`. This will make 
  the `root` user switch to `ubuntu`.

Now, when you do `vagrant ssh`, it will effectively log you in as `ubuntu`